# About nodejs path in webpack, how webpack find modules in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, resolve

I use webpack-dev-server to resolve some typescripts.

My configuration file:

```
module.exports={
entry: "./src/index.ts",
output: {
    filename: "main.js"
},
resolve:{
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', 'js'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), "node_modules"]
}
...
}
```

Then output of commandline:

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js
i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8089/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from ./dist
× ｢wdm｣:
ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8089
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './overlay' in 'F:\workspace\tslearn\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
@ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8089 10:14-34
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8089 ./src/index.ts
```

the index.js in webpack-dev-server\client.js is:

```
var stripAnsi = require('strip-ansi');

var socket = require('./socket');

var overlay = require('./overlay');

var _require = require('./utils/log'),
```

The ./overlay.js is under the path "F:\workspace\tslearn\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client"

But the js still can not find it.

the vscode give me indication is:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module './socket'. 'f:/workspace/tslearn/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

How to fix it? what is different between Typescript and JavaScript on this?

Comment: You're trying to import a Javascript file (socket.js) into a Typescript file (index.ts) and the Javascript file has no typings. Add type declarations for socket.js, or turn off noImplicitAny in your tsconfig.json. You haven't given us enough info to diagnose the other problem: please provide your directory structure.

Comment: Do you know how to import javascript fille into a typescript if I use extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', 'js']

Comment: Again, you posted *two different error messages*. The fix for the one about `Could not find a declaration file for module './socket'.` can be fixed by creating one, or turning off noImplicitAny in the tsconfig.json options. Then there's `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './overlay'` which again, you haven't given us enough to solve. Please provide at the very least the information requested.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, actually, I have many errors, I think the socket and overlay are same kind issue.

Answer (score 0):

Background
Webpack itself doesn't deal with Typescript, it uses a helper such as ts-loader or other depending on the webpack configuration file `webpack.config.js`. Example of configuration:

```js
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',
              options: {
                transpileOnly: true,
                happyPackMode: true,
                configFile: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
              },
            }
          ],
        },
        ...
        other rules
        ...
      ]
```

ts-loader will transpile Typescript using configuration settings in `tsconfig.json`.

> How to fix it? what is different between Typescript and JavaScript on this?

`tsconfig.json` should have `"allowJs": true` otherwise Typescript compiler won't consider .js files while resolving imports. Also Typescript compiler should be able to find `overlay.js` and other .js files. It will search in a few places documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) under *How TypeScript resolves modules* heading.

Finally, in order to get rid of declaration related errors, write declaration files, for example `overlay.d.ts` and place it next to the corresponding .js files.